# probability counting problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A deck of cards is shuffled. Let n be a positive integer = {1,2,3,4,5,6......52}. What is the probability that the first 3 in the deck is the nth card? Find a formula that holds for each n between 1 and 52

Re hints:

1) the first 3 cannot occur at n>49, 2) for n < 50, first 3 doesn't have a preference. if 3 is at n=1,there are 51 choose 3 ways that u can put the other 3s. If 3 is at n=2, there are 50 choose 3 ways til u hit when n =49, there is only 1 way u can put the other 3s.

Comment: The probability of that is $0$, because $3$ cards cannot just turn into $1$ card, so please fix up your question! In addition, please share your own efforts on this question if you're expecting others to make an effort for you. This is not a 'do my homework for free' service.

Comment: I presume you are meaning that out of the four $3's$ in the deck, the first one occurs in the $n_{th}$ position ? Pl. confirm, and give your thoughts.

Comment: @trueblueanil yes

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1) Can the first $3$ occur at $n>49 ?$

2) For $1 \le n \le 49$, does the first $3$ have any preference for position ?

Can you now get the probability distribution ?

---

For $1 \le n \le 49,\;\; \Bbb P(n) = \dfrac{\binom{52-n}{3}}{\binom{52}4},\;\; 0\;$ otherwise

Comment: 1) the first 3 cannot occur at n>49, 
2) for n < 50, first 3 doesn't have a preference. if 3 is at n=1,there are 51 choose 3 ways that u can put the other 3s. If 3 is at n=2, there are 50 choose 3 ways til u hit when n =49, there is only 1 way u can put the other 3s.

Comment: Good. That is why we say you must put your thoughts when you pose a question. It is necessary to show your effort in the question part, else it is likely to get closed, so I'm transferring your comment there, and formalizing the answer. Pl. bear it in mind in future.